# Simulating UITableView scrolling effect in a side bar like Facebook's iPhone App

Tags: iphone, facebook, uitableview, scroll

I'm working on an app and I've recently added in a sidebar and I want it to act like Facebook's. They have a search bar anchored at the top, as a custom header I'm sure (since the other section headers replace it as you scroll), but the header doesn't allow bouncing. The thing that I can't figure out how to do is allow for bouncing on the cells within the tableview. Setting tableview.bounces = NO locks everything in place, but doesn't allow for the cells to bounce like I want them to.

In summary, I have a sidebar that slides over. I have one section, with a custom header. I want that header anchored(locked) to the position it is initialized in (no bouncing above the header). Then I want the cells within the tableview to be able to bounce at the top and bottom of the view.

Thanks for any help or input.

Comment: This doesn't really count as an answer, but this might be what your looking for: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ghsidebarnav, if not I guess you could always look at the source code to figure it out?

Comment: I looked into this, hoping I could find the solution within his code, but it was very confusing. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a section or table header, why not just position a "header" view above the table view, and make the tableview smaller?

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the correct answer. Basically I just subclassed the tableview into a UIView, then added the header as another view, and the tableview below it with no section headers.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is just a fancy `UIScrollView` that is also a `UIScrollViewDelegate` for itself.  You could override `scrollViewDidScroll:` and set the position of the header to always anchor to the top when the contentOffset.y is > 0.